# Strategy Testing Entry Price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How to get exact entry on specific price in strategy testing coding. Normally either it take place on when the bar is closed or the next bar is open with CLOSE price only. But I want on specific price like says high bar of current candle + 4 pips, if that did not hit then ignore the entry in strategy testing. Is it possible?

```
if buy 
     strategy.entry(id="Long", direction=strategy.long)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgTM8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate your target price and place a limit order by using `limit` or `stop` arguments of the `strategy.entry()` function.

> **limit (series int/float)** An optional parameter. Limit price of the order. If it is specified, the order type is either 'limit', or
> 'stop-limit'. 'NaN' should be specified for any other order type.
>
> **stop (series int/float)** An optional parameter. Stop price of the order. If it is specified, the order type is either 'stop', or
> 'stop-limit'. 'NaN' should be specified for any other order type.

Comment: I tried this but not hitting order on exact value.                                                      strategy.entry(id="Long", direction=strategy.long, stop = Buy_true)
Here Buy_true is the specific price.

Comment: I have added Image for understanding, pls can you reply on this?